# How to open File Manager and pick a directory before downloading file in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, rn-fetch-blob

I'm developing a React Native app for Android platform and I have to download file by using **rn-fetch-blob** library.
I find out some apps can open File Manager of Android and choose a directory when user download. So how can I do that?

My app download using writeFile method because it's a base64, not using fetch file from url.

Thanks for reading question and have a nice day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this package [react-native-scoped-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scoped-storage)

> ```
> import * as ScopedStorage from "react-native-scoped-storage"
>
> let dir = await ScopedStorage.openDocumentTree(true);
> ```
>
> Once the user selects a directory, we will recieve the information
> about the directory and its uri. Now we can use this uri to
> read/write.
>
> ```
> // We can store this directory in AsyncStorage for later use.
> await AsyncStorage.setItem('userMediaDirectory',JSON.stringify(dir));
> ```

Comment: thanks @Engr.Aftab Ufaq, it's work perfectly but when I download file next time, button "Use this folder" in File Manager is lost. I have to go back to previous folder and select destination folder again to see the button. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: for this you have to save your path in some Aysnc Storage and then use that.